# Array access arithmetic is done at compile time or runtime?

Tags: c

Let us say I have an array

```
int aVar[10];
...
...
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    aVar[i] = i*10;
```

Here, what I know is that the array is referenced as a pointer and the location of the indexed value is calculated with something like: `(base address of aVar) + sizeof(int) * i`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

My questions:

Is this calculation already done by the compiler before running the executable, or this arithmetic calculation of finding exact location in the array done while executing?

Of course, we can not get the address of `aVar` at the compile time.

Comment: Most C compilers provide an option that will make them spew the translated assembly source. You can then look inside it to find out how the compiler implements array access. It is very platform-, compiler- and optimisation level dependent stuff though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nominally it is done at runtime, but the standard doesn't care provided that the result is correct (the standard calls this the "as-if" rule). It's up to whoever wrote your C implementation, and it might depend what optimization options you use.

If the compiler unrolls the loop then it would know the offset of `aVar[0]`, `aVar[1]` etc from the stack pointer, the same as it knows the offset of `aVar` from the stack pointer. So there's no unavoidable obstacle to the code looking something like:

```
store 0 at some constant offset from the stack pointer
store 10 at a slightly larger constant offset from the stack pointer
etc.
```

Comment: Although, "In theory" might not be the best way to describe it. Loop unrolling is in practice, after all.

Comment: Of course the compiler can't do that if the loop limit isn't constant. The answer comes down to good compilers doing what they can (considering flags that determine space/time and compile/runtime tradeoffs) at compile time and the rest at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, in case it isn't clear this is my theory that compilers can do it, rather than the standard's theory. The standard doesn't care and therefore doesn't trouble itself to have a theory.

Comment: I re-read, and decided that "in theory" might cause someone to think that I'm saying it *won't* happen in practice. So I removed it.

Answer (score 4):

"Of course we can not get the address of aVar at the compile time?"

Yes, actually, we can, or close enough. If it's global or static then it will occupy a fixed location which the linker can resolve -- not quite compile time but not at run time. And if it's on the stack, the offset from the stack pointer is known at compile time so nothing needs to be calculated on machines (such as PC's) where addresses can take the form offset + content of register.

Comment: So,jim you mean to say if i declare aVar @ global scope, then is the scenario is different?

Comment: I mean global or static will use "absolute" addressing (no register), and local will use "relative" addressing involving a register (the stack pointer).

Answer (score 0):

"cannot get the address of aVar at compile time".  True, but the compiler can generate code to compute its address *before* entering the loop and performance wise its the loop body that needs optimization, not the pre-loop code.

A good compiler optimizing this will either put that base address into a register inside the loop so it doesn't have to refetch it, or notice that your array accesses sweep the array the same way the index does.  A really clever compiler will realize the i*10 is computed off the array index and that nothing else is, and replace the index, too.  So the optimized code compiled is probably more like:

```
int aVar[10];
...
...
register int* p = &aVar;  // my C syntax may be slight wrong here
for(i=0; i10<10*10; i10+=10)
    *p = i10;
```

(The loop could also be reversed, so i10 could count from 100 downto zero. Since subtraction often produces condition codes in widely used machines, this can save a compare instruction.)